# Feed import not creating new nodes

Tags: feeds

I've got a feed import set up using the **HTTP Fetcher**. It creates nodes of a certain type. I need it to import repeatedly so I've got **Periodic Import** set to **As often as possible**. I've got **Import on Submission** and **Update existing Nodes** checked.

However, the feed imports and creates only **25 nodes** on my first manual import. After that it does not create any new nodes either when doing so manually or when the cron run triggers it.

This is a **youtube feed** pulling videos of a certain publisher and parsing the data with the [Feeds youtube](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_youtube) module. I also have a field that I am using as **Unique**.

Any idea what might be going on??

**NOTE:** There are no error messages in any of the logs.

Comment: check if you arent getting the same videos each time ... (that happned to me last time, cant remember what i did to solve it though :)

Comment: If I set it to "Do not update existing nodes" it says "No new nodes created" upon 'importing'. If I set it to 'replace' or 'update' existing nodes, it updates all nodes. 

Anybody have any idea how this module works?

Comment: i think the problem is in youtube paging / ordering the results. that way you get the same set for each request and you will have to find a way to ask for different videos (hard to tell how to do it without knowing more detail)

Comment: @mojzis Hmm yea that makes sense! This is the URL I'm using: gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?alt=rss&orderby=published&author=cangrejerossanturce
Any idea how I can get a youtube feed that isn't paged...?

Comment: I also noticed that the video descriptions are being trimmed, much how they are trimmed in RSS feed pages like this one: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/videos?q=cangrejerossanturce&client=ytapi-youtube-search&v=2

Answer (score 0):

According to the [specs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#Searching_for_videos), you can set the `max-results` parameter up to 50. For succeeding searches the `start-index` can be increased. I guess you will have to do this manually to fill the database for the first time, or you can try to use the [Feeds Crawler](http://drupal.org/project/feeds_crawler).